# Customer Password Security Rules

Tags: customer-account, security, password

I would like for my customers to have to adhere to certain rules when creating an account/creating a password. These rules are for password security and are as follows:

- Greater than 8 characters
- Contains Uppercase
- Contains Lowercase
- Contains Number
- Contains a Special Character

Is there a way I can enforce this within Magento so that my customers have greater security on their accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default there is no way to impose passwords for customers in Magento.  There are plethora of JQuery plugins if you chose to go that route.

Dropbox however has a very good Library for such:

- https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn
- Demo: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209/zxcvbn/test/index.html

Also to note:

- [Passwords in sign up email. Bad practice? PCI compliant?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5914/passwords-in-sign-up-email-bad-practice-pci-compliant)

Further reading:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51060/should-i-reject-obviously-poor-passwords

Comment: Great answer. The password in email applies to Magento 1.6 and lower IIRC and was changed to hashed time limited link in 1.7. One of the upgrade pitfalls if you have your transactional email templates in the database.