# Why the Magento 1.9.3.4 welcome email still send customer password in text plain?

Tags: magento-1.9, password

Why `Magento 1.9.3.4` welcome email still send customer password in `plain text` ?

I think this is not safe at all. I know that I can replace the line `<strong>Password</strong>: {{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}` to not show the passwords

I thought, after 1.9, it won't show passwords any more, but accidentally I found the welcome email include the password in plain text .

I wonder whether my magento codes have Security problem, because I think the password should not been seen and shown in any methods.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true that the **Welcome mail** contains the password in plain text,  but there are some who say that it is a **bad practice** and other **not** ! I let you read [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5992/48355) with the advantages and disadvantages and the [Magento Security Enhancements](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1930security-pwd)

In any case you can **change** it by making one of these two choices:

In `app/locale/YOURLANGUAGE/template/email/account_new.html` you find:

`<strong>Password</strong>: {{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}`

**Choice 1:** You can change this by changing this email template and either remove this line or replace it with something like:

`The password you have chosen when creating this account.`

**Choice 2:** You could also create a new email template in the Admin Panel via `System > Email Templates` and then set this new template in `System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options > Welcome Email`